# Twig template not receiving variables

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have a CMS page that includes a component called `pageTitle` that will display a formatted page title. I am trying to pass a variable to that component, but it does not seem to be receiving it. I have the following in my page:

```
title = "Test"

[pageTitle]
title="Test"
==
{% component 'pageTitle' title="Test" %}
```

which (I think) should be using 3 different ways to pass a variable to that component, and in `components/pagetitle/default.htm` I have (among other HTML):

```
{{ title }}
```

The HTML renders fine, but the variable is not being outputted.

I have also tried putting the following in my `components/pagetitle/PageTitle.php` main class file:

```
public function defineProperties()
{
    return [
        'title'    => [
            'title'       => 'Title',
            'description' => 'The page title',
            'type'        => 'string',
        ],
    ];
}
```

However that also has no effect.

It is probably also worth noting that in my `components/pagetitle/default.htm` if I add a header section, like:

```
title = "Test"
==
HTML content here
```

the whole thing is displayed in the output HTML, including the header. So I'm wondering if it is being interpreted by something other than the Twig interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, i am pretty sure there is nothing to intercept.

can you try this one as its working on my local

```
<div id="tile-area">
    <h1>default one {{ __SELF__.property('title') }}</h1>
</div>
```

it should work.

further more you can take reference from here : https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#component-properties

if any doubt please comment

Comment: Yes, that works. What do you mean by "nothing to intercept"? I'm relatively new at learning October CMS.

Comment: `So I'm wondering if it is being interpreted by something other` so means there is no other thing is interpreted it wrong. cool your are new so if you need any help. post questions we are happy to help you +1